# Why is validationEngine() not working?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to make [this](http://taraontv.com/contact.html) contact form work with validation engine.

I am not able to understand why validation is not fired when pressing the Submit button. I have already spent over one hour doing debugging and so on.

You can notice that my form's input elements have `class="validate[required]"` and I also bound the form to validation engine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
        $("#registerForm").validationEngine();
    });
</script>
```

Do you see anything that I am doing wrong? A demo working page for this jQuery plugin is [here](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html).

Comment: Well for one, I'm seeing a bunch of these errors: `Uncaught Error: jQueryValidate: an ID attribute is required for this field: comment class:validate[required]`

Comment: Thanks Robet...Unbelievable...I simply did not see that error..Now I put ids for each of my input fields and it's working!...You can put that as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its mandatory to use an ID attribute for the input tags. So write an ID attribute to the  input tag that you need to provide validation using validation engine plugin.